Vue: Cannot find module ~~~ or its corresponding type declarations. in Vitest test module
I'm using vite and vitest.
vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), VueDevTools()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: '@',
        replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      },
      {
        find: '@mocks',
        replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./mock', import.meta.url)),
      },
    ],
  },
});

vitest.config.ts
export default mergeConfig(viteConfig, defineConfig({
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths()]
}));

tsconfig.app.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@mocks/*": ["mock/*"]
    }
  }
}

Procject structure

root

mock/
src/
tests/converter.test.ts



The Alias import works in src/. 
Now I have a problem. in converter.test.ts, when I import module with alias, (@/, @mock) 
Cannot find module ~~~ or its corresponding type declarations.<< has occured.
Did I missed something?
Environment
vue : 3.4.21
vite : 5.1.6
The test and run serve are working well in Intellij. And when I Crtl + Mouse Left click -> Can go to file.
But the error message is showing and in VSCode test and run serve not work.
Solution
I resolved this issue. answer was in tsconfig.app.json
{
  "include": ["src/**/*, "tests/**/*"]
}

This worked to me


It's not confirmed that a config with custom name is applied, tsconfig.app.json . This is a common explanation for a config that doesn't work as expected
